# Is this question really that bad?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewing close votes and thought this should stay open:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209803

(Specifically, edit #7.) Turned out it was an audit, closed as unclear.
I don't quite see what's wrong with it.

I had thought of it as sort of a noobish database question. Would you
say it was closed as an unclear database-and-website-integration
question? It could be clearer, but I don't think it's bad enough to
close, at least as of revision 7.

Comment: Are you really making an argument that this question needs *more* answers to explain that a dbase table should have a primary key?  Or are you just chagrined by failing the audit?

Comment: The question is not good enough to be reopened, and appears to be satisfactorily answered anyway.  Nothing more to see here.

Comment: @HansPassant  He's probably confused by the fact that it's a bad audit(and rightly so)

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm arguing that it wasn't bad enough to close. We don't close questions just because they've been adequately answered. We close them because there are serious problems with them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'm not saying it should be reopened. I'm saying that it isn't clear to me why it was considered bad enough to close. I would like clarification on that point, to improve the quality of future reviews.

Comment: I would have voted to close it as unclear.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yes, I gathered that. Can you help me to see why? Where does my thought process differ from yours? Is there anything specific that seems unclear? Perhaps it's because you're more familiar with database questions than I am?

Comment: For starters, how is "using a column with a duplicate value" relevant to the question or it's answer?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, it's not well stated, but I took that to mean the OP wanted to delete the third row because it has the same `Age` and `ItemNo` as the fourth row. (Yes, of course one should use `index`. It's noobish, as I said.)

Comment: Ah, the meta effect. The accepted answer gets upvotes while I watch even though it's deleting the wrong row from the database (because the question was edited after it was asked).

Answer (score 2):

Although It's not the best question I've ever seen,  I don't think that closeable enough that an audit should be made of it.

I read the question's first revision and understood it.

he wanted to delete the third(or other specific number) row in the result of a sql query.

There was a little bit of confusion due to the fact that one of his columns was called **index**, and because of that It's understandable that people might downvote and vote to close.

But it's also understandable that one would vote to leave it open.  The decision to close is up for interpretation, and this is not a clear enough "close" that it has any business being an audit question.

Comment: In a roundabout way, I think you're saying what I was thinking: *it's not a good candidate for an audit question.*

Comment: That wasn't my focus, but I have to agree. Audit questions should be more clear-cut. They do say they're for making sure we're paying attention.